# How to create your own Windows XP Keyboard Mapping?

Tags: windows-xp

My father has found a Russian language keyboard mapping that he really likes [here](http://translit.ru/).  However, it is non-standard and therefore is not one that appears in the Languages (*Control Panel->Regional and Language Options->Languages->Details->Text Services And Input Languages->Add*) dropdown for keyboard layout selection.  To my understanding, it should be a simple task to create a new mapping - perhaps editing an XML file and a reboot.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Barring that, how would I go about writing a program to emulate this?  It seems like it would have to run in the system tray (I can figure that out), have a hook intercepting incoming keyboard input (no idea how to do this), convert it off a configuration file, and send it to whatever application and text window has current focus (again, no idea).  With any luck this should not be too hard.

Any advice?

Comment: It's worth noting that this question has [also been answered here](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's [this utility from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/tools/msklc.mspx)

> The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator
>   (MSKLC) extends the international
>   functionality of Windows 2000, Windows
>   XP, Windows Server 2003,and Windows
>   Vistas systems by allowing users to:

- Create new keyboard layouts from scratch
- Base a new layout on an existing one
- Modify an existing keyboard layout and build a new layout from it
- Multilingual input locales within edit control fields.
- Build keyboard layout DLLs for x86, x64, and IA64 platforms.
- Package the resulting keyboard layouts for subsequent delivery and installation.

Comment: I just applied my google-fu. I didn't know the answer, but I was pretty sure Microsoft must have done something here :)

Comment: To actually install the created keyboard, go to the `Project` menu and select `Build DLL and Setup Package` inside MSKLC, then install the generated MSI.

Comment: If you would like to switch between layouts using a single key press (I assigned F12 for this), and don't want to reassign ` for that (the other two options Ctrl+Shift and Left Alt+Ctrl are both not single key strokes), see this page http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/83557-need-r-to-send-alt-shift/ for how to use AutoHotkey to get pressing F12 to simulate "Alt+Ctrl". (In the answer given there, `r` is assigned, but replace "r" with "F12" in the two locations, and it works.)

Answer (score 1):

Try AutoHotKey (http://www.autohotkey.com/) i use it to get emacs keybindings in normal text editors, i'm sure it could tackle this too.

edit: the bit you're looking for is in the quickstart here: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#Send